# implementing dilation from scratch

Tags: python, opencv

I'm attempting to implement dilation from scratch instead of using OpenCV. I've attempting, using a simple kernel, scan over an image and 'stamp' the kernel onto the image when the kernel overlaps an existing white pixel.

```
[[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Code:

```
border = ksize//2
paddedIm = np.zeros((height + border*2, width + border*2))
paddedIm = cv2.copyMakeBorder(im, border, border, border, border, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = 0)
paddedDilatedIm = paddedIm.copy()


for h_i in range(border, height+border):
  for w_i in range(border,width+border):
    
    if im[h_i-border,w_i-border]:
        print("White Pixel Found @ {},{}".format(h_i,w_i))

        
        paddedDilatedIm[ h_i - border : (h_i + border)+1, w_i - border : (w_i + border)+1][1,1] = \
            np.amax(cv2.bitwise_and(paddedIm[ h_i - border : (h_i + border)+1, w_i - border : (w_i + border)+1] , element)) 
        
        
        
        print(paddedDilatedIm)
        plt.imshow(paddedDilatedIm);plt.show()
```

The above loop correctly id's a white pixel but fails to turn the centre pixel from `[h_i - border : (h_i + border)+1, w_i - border : (w_i + border)+1][1,1]` white.

How can I fix this?

Output:

```
White Pixel Found @ 6,6
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is `element`? What is the purpose of `cv2.bitwise_and` and `np.amax`? Why are you using `[1,1]` indexing?

Comment: @Rotem Hi, yes element is a 3x3 matrix [0,1,0 / 1,1,1 / 0,1,0] essentially a cross. cv2.bitwise_and to my knowledge places a 1 within the centre of the 3x3 matrix when both a 1 from paddedIm and element overlap. The 3x3 element shifts pixel by pixel across the image. When the element and a 1 from the image overlap the centre pixel (within 3x3) should convert to 1 (which is the np.amax of the matrix (max value)).

Comment: I think it should be `cv2.bitwise_or` instead of `cv2.bitwise_and`, but your implementation seems too complicated. Consider using intermediate variables, instead of putting everything in one line.

Comment: thanks @Rotem . It was a simple fix. I just needed to add == 0 to end of 'if im[h_i-border,w_i-border]'